# Detecting two intersecting circles with editable x, y, and radius in JavaFX

Tags: java, computational-geometry, javafx

I was actually pretty proud of this programming project that I came across in this book I'm working through. I only really had problems figuring out the formula for detecting whether or not the two circles had intersecting paths. I'm still getting the hang of object-oriented programming, primarily when and where to use `static`, `private`, `public`, etc... but I think I'm on the right path. Let me know what you think.

[image] [image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Created by John on 7/28/2014.
 */
public class Project16_8 extends Application {
    private static String intersectAnswer = "Two circles intersect? ";
    private static Label intersect;

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Initialize the intersect Label
        intersect = new Label(intersectAnswer + "No");

        // Pane to hold the circles
        Pane circlePane = new Pane();
        circlePane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        CircleObject circle1 = new CircleObject(52.0, 60.0, 30);
        CircleObject circle2 = new CircleObject(180.0, 56.0, 40);
        circlePane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2);

        // Circle 1 info Pane
        Pane circle1Pane = new Pane();
        CircleInfo circle1Info = new CircleInfo("Enter circle 1 info: ",
            52.0, 60.0, 30);
        circle1Pane.getChildren().add(circle1Info);

        // Circle 2 info Pane
        Pane circle2Pane = new Pane();
        CircleInfo circle2Info = new CircleInfo("Enter circle 2 info: ",
            180.0, 56.0, 40);
        circle2Pane.getChildren().add(circle2Info);

        // HBox to hold the two circle info pane's
        HBox circleInfoHBox = new HBox(5);
        circleInfoHBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        circleInfoHBox.getChildren().addAll(circle1Pane, circle2Pane);

        // Redraw Circles button and set ActionEvent Handler
        Button redrawCircles = new Button("Redraw Circles");
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = e -> {
            // Set circle1 variables
            circle1.setCenterX(circle1Info.getCenterX());
            circle1.setCenterY(circle1Info.getCenterY());
            circle1.setRadius(circle1Info.getRadius());

            // Set circle2 variables
            circle2.setCenterX(circle2Info.getCenterX());
            circle2.setCenterY(circle2Info.getCenterY());
            circle2.setRadius(circle2Info.getRadius());

            // Check to see if the circles intersect
            double circle1X = circle1.getCenterX();
            double circle1Y = circle1.getCenterY();
            double circle1Radius = circle1.getRadius();
            double circle2X = circle2.getCenterX();
            double circle2Y = circle2.getCenterY();
            double circle2Radius = circle2.getRadius();

            if (checkIntersection(circle1X, circle1Y, circle1Radius,
                    circle2X, circle2Y, circle2Radius)) {
                intersect.setText(intersectAnswer + "Yes");
            } else {
                intersect.setText(intersectAnswer + "No");
            }
        };
        redrawCircles.setOnAction(handler);
        circle1Info.getTfCenterX().setOnAction(handler);
        circle1Info.getTfCenterY().setOnAction(handler);
        circle1Info.getTfRadius().setOnAction(handler);
        circle2Info.getTfCenterX().setOnAction(handler);
        circle2Info.getTfCenterY().setOnAction(handler);
        circle2Info.getTfRadius().setOnAction(handler);

        // VBox to hold everything
        VBox pane = new VBox();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(2));
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(intersect, circlePane, circleInfoHBox,
                redrawCircles);

        // Create a scene and add it to the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("IntersectingCircles"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    /** Compares the two circles to make sure they don't intersect */
    public boolean checkIntersection(double circle1X, double circle1Y,
        double circle1Radius, double circle2X, double circle2Y,
        double circle2Radius) {
        // dx and dy are the vertical and horizontal distances
        double dx = circle2X - circle1X;
        double dy = circle2Y - circle1Y;

        // Determine the straight-line distance between centers.
        double d = Math.sqrt((dy * dy) + (dx * dx));

        // Check Intersections
        if (d > (circle1Radius + circle2Radius)) {
            // No Solution. Circles do not intersect
            return false;
        } else if (d < Math.abs(circle1Radius - circle2Radius)) {
            // No Solution. one circle is contained in the other
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    /** Create a Circle object and set it's editable attributes */
    public class CircleObject extends Pane {
        // Data Fields
        private Circle circle;
        private double radius;
        private double centerX;
        private double centerY;
        private Paint fill;
        private Paint stroke;

        /** Create Default Constructor */
        public CircleObject () {
            // Set data fields
            this.centerX = 52.0;
            this.centerY = 60.0;
            this.radius = 30;

            // Paint the Circle
            paintCircle();
        }

        /** Create Secondary Constructor */
        public CircleObject (double centerX, double centerY, double radius) {
            // Set data fields
            this.centerX = centerX;
            this.centerY = centerY;
            this.radius = radius;
            this.fill = null;
            this.stroke = Color.BLACK;

            // Paint the Circle
            paintCircle();
        }

        /** Get centerX */
        public double getCenterX() {
            return this.centerX;
        }

        /** Set centerX */
        public void setCenterX(double centerX) {
            this.centerX = centerX;
            this.circle.setCenterX(this.centerX);
        }

        /** Get centerY */
        public double getCenterY() {
            return this.centerY;
        }

        /** Set centerY */
        public void setCenterY(double centerY) {
            this.centerY = centerY;
            this.circle.setCenterY(this.centerY);
        }

        /** Get radius */
        public double getRadius() {
            return this.radius;
        }

        /** Set radius */
        public void setRadius(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.circle.setRadius(this.radius);
        }

        /** Get Fill */
        public Paint getFill() {
            return this.fill;
        }

        /** Set Fill */
        public void setFill(Paint fill) {
            this.fill = fill;
            this.circle.setFill(fill);
        }

        /** Get Stroke */
        public Paint getStroke() {
            return this.stroke;
        }

        /** Set Stroke */
        public void setStroke(Paint stroke) {
            this.stroke = stroke;
            this.circle.setStroke(this.stroke);
        }

        /** Paint the circle object */
        public void paintCircle() {
            // Create a circle object
            this.circle = new Circle();
            this.circle.setCenterX(this.centerX);
            this.circle.setCenterY(this.centerY);
            this.circle.setRadius(this.radius);
            this.circle.setFill(this.fill);
            this.circle.setStroke(this.stroke);
            getChildren().add(this.circle);
        }
    }

    /** Create a Circle info control VBox */
    public class CircleInfo extends VBox {
        // Data Fields
        private String circleLabel;
        private double centerX;
        private double centerY;
        private double radius;

        // Text Fields
        private TextField tfCenterX;
        private TextField tfCenterY;
        private TextField tfRadius;

        /** Default Constructor */
        public CircleInfo() {
            // Set Data Fields
            this.circleLabel = "Enter circle Info: ";
            this.centerX = 52.0;
            this.centerY = 60.0;
            this.radius = 30;

            // Paint the circleInfo VBox
            paintCircleInfo();
        }

        /** Create Secondary Constructor */
        public CircleInfo(String circleLabel, double centerX,
                          double centerY, double radius) {
            // Set Data Fields
            this.circleLabel = circleLabel;
            this.centerX = centerX;
            this.centerY = centerY;
            this.radius = radius;

            // Paint the circleInfo VBox
            paintCircleInfo();
        }

        /** Get Center X */
        public double getCenterX() {
            return this.centerX = Double.parseDouble(tfCenterX.getText());
        }

        /** Set Center X */
        public void setCenterX(double centerX) {
            this.centerX = centerX;
            tfCenterX.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.centerX));
        }

        /** Get Center Y */
        public double getCenterY() {
            return this.centerY = Double.parseDouble(tfCenterY.getText());
        }

        /** Set Center Y */
        public void setCenterY(double centerY) {
            this.centerY = centerY;
            tfCenterY.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.centerY));
        }

        /** Get Radius */
        public double getRadius() {
            return this.radius = Double.parseDouble(tfRadius.getText());
        }

        /** Set Radius */
        public void setRadius(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
            tfRadius.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.radius));
        }

        /** Get tfCenterX */
        public TextField getTfCenterX() {
            return this.tfCenterX;
        }

        /** Get tfCenterY */
        public TextField getTfCenterY() {
            return this.tfCenterY;
        }

        /** Get tfRadius */
        public TextField getTfRadius() {
            return this.tfRadius;
        }

        /** Paint the circleInfo VBox */
        public void paintCircleInfo() {
            // Create TextFields
            this.tfCenterX = new TextField();
            this.tfCenterX.setPrefColumnCount(2);
            this.tfCenterX.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.centerX));
            this.tfCenterY = new TextField();
            this.tfCenterY.setPrefColumnCount(2);
            this.tfCenterY.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.centerY));
            this.tfRadius = new TextField();
            this.tfRadius.setPrefColumnCount(2);
            this.tfRadius.setText(String.format("%.1f", this.radius));

            // Create Labels, add TextFields, set content to the right
            Label lbInfo = new Label(circleLabel);
            lbInfo.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            Label lbCenterX = new Label("Center x: ");
            lbCenterX.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            Label lbCenterY = new Label("Center y: ");
            lbCenterY.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            Label lbRadius = new Label("Radius: ");
            lbRadius.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            // Add TextField and corresponding Label elements to GridPane
            GridPane pane = new GridPane();
            pane.setHgap(5);
            pane.addRow(1, lbCenterX, tfCenterX);
            GridPane.setHalignment(tfCenterX, HPos.RIGHT);
            pane.addRow(2, lbCenterY, tfCenterY);
            GridPane.setHalignment(tfCenterY, HPos.RIGHT);
            pane.addRow(3, lbRadius, tfRadius);
            GridPane.setHalignment(tfRadius, HPos.RIGHT);

            // Add main label and GridPane to VBox
            this.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
            getChildren().addAll(lbInfo, pane);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Constructor

   ```
   CircleInfo(String circleLabel, double centerX, double centerY, double radius)
   ```

   can be simplified to

   ```
   CircleInfo(String circleLabel, CircleObject obj)
   ```

   because the constructor can get x, y and radius from `CircleObject`.
2. The same for `checkIntersection(...)`. This method can belong to `CircleObject`, such that you can call it from the object itself, i.e., `circle1.checkIntersection(circle2)`. The code is more readable, and the method is easier to extend with polymorphism to support `SquareObject` in the future. Property settings for `CircleObject` can also be simplified.
3. `paintCircleInfo()` re-creates labels and edits the box every time `Redraw Cirlce` is clicked. This can be a performance issue, so usually these items are only created in the first pass.
4. `private static String intersectAnswer = ...;` is good because you use `intersectAnswer` as a constant. It can be better by adding modifier `final` because you are not going to change it. Meanwhile, naming convention for constant in Java would capitalize letters and words are separated with under score, i.e., `private static final String INTERSECT_ANWSER = ...` is better.
5. Try to remove modifier `static` from `private static Label intersect;`. You may refer to: [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it that was some very good advice. That was a great idea with the checkIntersection and passing the object itself

Comment: Also I liked #4, I guess I was just trying to make it easier to create those boxes while reducing clutter in the start method, but now that you mention it I don't suppose it was a good tradeoff and probably just increased the size of my source rather then cutting back on clutter like I intended.

Answer (score 6):

**Do not use underscores on Class names :**

```
public class Project16_8 extends Application { ...
```

change this to

```
public class InterceptingCirclesApplication extends Application {
```

also the `start()` is like the main method, keep it simple.

There is too much going on in your start method.

change it to only contain 4-6 lines

```
    Node mainView = new MainView();
    Scene scene = new Scene(mainView);
    primaryStage.setTitle("IntersectingCircles"); 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); 
    primaryStage.show();
```

create a `MainView` class to conatin the main Interface

---

again, from the book Clean Code

> Long lists of imports are daunting to the reader. We don’t want to
>   clutter up the tops of our modules with 80 lines of imports.

I find this to be lot of imports too. But It's still somewhat OK,

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Use wildcards `*` to reduce number of imports. If you feel the top of the class is cluttered.

```
@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
```

This falls under too much information category.

```
/**
 * Created by John on 7/28/2014.
 */
```

Use the `@author` java-doc annotation to specify the author.

You do not need to specify the date of creation use Revision control instead.
Next thing you know is you will be writing a log up there.

Comment: In Java the convention is to show all imports and not use *.

Comment: @toto2 : review process is opinion based. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, for the input. I am currently working on my first big project which is going to be a poker game. I agree on the main method and I figure it would make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: And yeah I guess I got in too much of a habit of writing that down on the Override as I was learning